# Pandas: Adding column via arithmetic on all matching indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Edit: Added a row with no matched index to demonstrate expected behavior**

I have the following two DataFrames:

`requests`:

```
                requests
asn pop country
1   1   us      100
        br      50
    2   br      200
    3   hk      150
    4   uk      100
2   1   us      300
...
```

`traffic`:

```
        total capacity
asn pop
1   1   53    1000
    2   15    1000
    3   103   10000
2   1   254   10000
...
```

I wish to add a new column to the `requests` DataFrame with a value equal to `traffic["total"] / traffic["capacity"]`, aligned on the two matching indexes.

I tried the following:

```
>>>requests["network"] = traffic["total"] / traffic["capacity"]
>>>requests
                requests network
asn pop country
1   1   us      100      NaN
        br      50       NaN
    2   br      200      NaN
    3   hk      150      NaN
    4   uk      100      NaN
2   1   us      300      NaN
...
```

When **all three** indexes are available, this has worked for me before. However in this instance I only have two indexes, so it seems to fail.

### Expected Output

```
>>>requests
                requests network
asn pop country
1   1   us      100      0.053
        br      50       0.053
    2   br      200      0.015
    3   hk      150      0.0103
    4   uk      100      NaN
2   1   us      300      0.0254
...
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What should be the value for different countries having same asn and pop? The same value? If so, reset the index at the last level, do the operation and append it to the index again?

Comment: cause index is the key doing the new column creation, `requests` and `traffic` have different index

Comment: Two different countries with the same asn and pop are expected to have the same value. @jezrael's solution (old solution, not new solution) worked exactly as expected. I can update the question with the expected output, regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem your `MultiIndex` not matched, so get `NaN`s. solution is add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

```
requests['network'] =  traffic["total"].div(traffic["capacity"])
                                       .reindex(requests.index, method='ffill')
print (requests)
                 requests  network
asn pop country                   
1   1   us            100   0.0530
        br             50   0.0530
    2   br            200   0.0150
    3   hk            150   0.0103
2   1   us            300   0.0254
```

Old solution with `reset_index` + `set_index`:

```
requests = requests.reset_index(level=2)
requests['network'] =  traffic["total"].div(traffic["capacity"])
requests = requests.set_index('country', append=True)
print (requests)
                 requests  network
asn pop country                   
1   1   us            100   0.0530
        br             50   0.0530
    2   br            200   0.0150
    3   hk            150   0.0103
2   1   us            300   0.0254
```

Comment: The most recently updated solution (using `traffic["total"].div(traffic["capacity"]).reindex(requests.index, method="ffill")`) gave me some weird results when I tested in the Python REPL, but your earlier solution (using `.reset_index()` and `.set_index()`) gave the expected output and ran faster than @Wen's solution

Comment: Interesting, maybe buggy.

Comment: The "new" solution seemed to take any row for which there wasn't a matching index and instead of assigning it `NaN` is assigned it the first unmatched value from the other DataFrame. If it weren't for that bug, though, it ran 4-5x faster :P

Comment: Idea - sometimes help upgrade to last version of pandas, there buggy should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ..

```
requestes=requestes.reset_index().set_index(['asn','pop'])
requestes['network']=traffic["total"] / traffic["capacity"]
requestes.reset_index().set_index(['asn','pop','country'])
Out[140]: 
                 requests  network
asn pop country                   
1   1   us            100   0.0530
        br             50   0.0530
    2   br            200   0.0150
    3   hk            150   0.0103
2   1   us            300   0.0254
```